# How do we install new libraries for c++ mingw?

Tags: windows, c++, mingw

I wanted to learn about 'ncurses' library.But I am a beginner and couldn't understand how to get the library setup and usable.Do you just copy the library files and start using it or is there something that i should do specifically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I am using mingw in windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Do you just copy the library files and start using it?

On Windows you should use [PDCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/):

> [Download the zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/), unpack it wherever you typically put
>   external libraries, and check the readme, which tells you the
>   following:
>
> > PDCurses has been ported to DOS, OS/2, Win32, X11 and SDL. A directory containing the port-specific source files exists for each of
> >     these platforms. Build instructions are in the README file for each
> >     platform.
>
> The readme file in the Win32 directory tells you that there are
>   makefiles for several different compilers. In short, you run `make`:
>
> ```
>  make -f makefilename
> ```
>
> It tells mentions a couple of options you can set, including WIDE and
>   UTF8.
>
> To then *use* the library, add the directory that contains *curses.h*
>   to your include path and link with the *pdcurses.lib* file that `make`
>   generates for you. How you modify your include path and your linked
>   libraries depends on your development environment and is largely
>   irrelevant to PDCurses.

Source [How do I install PDCurses in Windows for use with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301713/3536342) by [Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy)

More detailed instructions below.

---

#### So are `ncurses` and `PDcurses` the same?

> PDCurses (Pubic Domain Curses) is the multi-platform, public domain
>   implementation of the terminal display library NCurses.
>
> NCurses (New Curses) is an implementation of Curses (a play on the
>   term cursor optimization), both of which are terminal control
>   libraries for UNIX and UNIX-like systems.
>
> Although not identical, PDCurses, NCurses, and Curses enable
>   programmers to add mouse support, screen painting, colors,
>   key-mapping, windows, and more to text-based applications without
>   regard to the terminal type. An example of PDCurses in use is shown
>   [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20151114214632/http://www.projectpluto.com:80/win32a.htm).
>
> MingW (Minimalist GNU for Windows) is a minimal Open Source
>   programming environment for developing Windows native applications not
>   requiring 3rd-party Runtime DLLs. However, MingW does utilize some
>   Microsoft DLLs provided by the Microsoft C runtime library. It
>   includes the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) and associated tools, the
>   GNU binutils.

Source [Adding PDCurses to MingW](http://cects.com/adding-pdcurses-to-mingw/)

---

#### Adding PDCurses to MingW

> **Steps**
>
> > Download the PDCurses version 3.4 file ([Download pdc34dllw.zip (86.9 KB)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/latest/download?source=files)) from Sourceforge.com and unzip it. This version is the Win32 DLL
> >     for console with Unicode.
>
> Copy the extracted files to the following folders:
>
> - `pdcurses.lib` to MingW's `/lib` folder
> - `curses.h` and `panel.h` to MingW's `/include` folder
> - `pdcures.dll` to MingW's `/bin` folder
>
> **Test**
>
> Example command using PDCurses to compile the file checkthis.c:
>
> ```
> gcc checkthis.c -o checkthis -lpdcurses
> ```
>
> If the following code compiles, PDCurses is installed correctly.
>
> ```
> /*  checkthis.c  */
> #include <curses.h>
> int main()
>   {
>   initscr();
>   wclear(stdscr);
>   printw("hello world\n");
>   wrefresh(stdscr);
>   system("pause");
>   endwin();
>   }
> ```

Source [Adding PDCurses to MingW](http://cects.com/adding-pdcurses-to-mingw/)

Comment: So is ncurses and PDcurses the same?Thanks for the help.Also which file do i have to download?There are so may of them.

Comment: @Allen They are both implementations of curses. There are a few differences. See http://wmcbrine.com/pdcurses/doc/PDCurses.txt and http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html for the gory details :)

Comment: @Allen Take the latest. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/latest/download?source=files

Comment: Ok..i downloaded pdcurs34.zip.Is that the file and do i have to download those dlls

Comment: @Allen Alternatively ditch mingw and use cywin instead. there are cygwin ncurses and g++ packages

Comment: The dll's are required at runtime.

Comment: Sorry if I'm troubling you,but please can you give me a step by step detailed description.I'm not getting it.

Comment: The instructions are in the answer. I don't have anything else. I don't use mingw or Windows 10.

Comment: http://cects.com/adding-pdcurses-to-mingw/   Hey found this.

Comment: @Allen Great. I will add it to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The ncurses library is available for MinGW. Simply open CMD, or run PowerShell and run `mingw-get install ncurses`, mingw-get will both download and install the package. Just make sure the path to your MinGW bin folder is linked to your system path, and you should be able to use ncurses without trouble.

By the way, be certain to use the `-lncurses` option when you compile your code.